# how to show a Blog detail link in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, strapi

I want to show the Detail of a Blog in a different link in Angular. I already have a Blog file (blog.component.ts) and an Angular service where I can get all the blogs data from an API backend made with Strapi. There is one button in every single blog, which allows you to view the detail or complete Blog in a different link calling the unique ID, that is named 'pagina.component.ts'.
For that purpose, I think I must call the ID of every single Blog.

Here is my blog.component.html, where I already have the list of my blogs:

```
<section class="articles">

  <article class="blue-article" *ngFor="let data of datas; index as i">
    <div class="articles-header">
      <time>{{ data.fecha }}</time>
      <span class="articles-header-tag-blue">{{ data.relevante }}</span>
      <span class="articles-header-category">
        <a href="#" class="blue" title="">{{ data.category.name }}</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="articles-content">
      <h1><a title="">{{ data.title }}</a></h1>
      <!--<img *ngIf="!data.image" class="foto" [src]="data.image.name" alt="foto">-->
      <div *ngIf="data.image">
        <img
          src="http://localhost:1337{{ data.image.url }}"
          alt="foto"
          width="100%"
        />
      </div>
      <p>
        {{ data.content }}
      </p>
      <h3>{{ data.description }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="articles-footer">
      <ul class="articles-footer-info">
        <li><a href="#" class="light-link" title=""><i class="pe-7s-comment"></i> 7 Respuestas</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="light-link" title=""><i class="pe-7s-like"></i> 1221</a></li>
      </ul>

      <a [routerLink]="['./pagina',i]" class="btn">Leer más</a>

    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Here is my blog.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { StrapiService } from '../../../services/strapi.service';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.scss']
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {

  datas:any=[];
  errores:string="";

  constructor(
    public strapiserv:StrapiService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.title.setTitle('Blog');

    this.strapiserv.getData().subscribe(res=>{

        this.datas= res as string[];

    }, error =>{
      console.log(error);
        if(error.status == 0){
            this.errores="Código del error: "+error.status+" \n Ha ocurrido un error del lado del cliente o un error de red.";
        }else{
            this.errores="Código del error: "+error.status+"\n\n"+error.statusText;
        }
    })

  }


}
```

Here is my Angular service named 'strapi.service.ts'

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StrapiService {

  REST_API: string ='http://localhost:1337/articles';
  //https://strapi-dot-gmal-api-313723.uc.r.appspot.com/
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  getData():Observable<any>{
    console.log();
    let API=this.REST_API;
    return this.httpClient.get(API,{headers:this.httpHeaders}) .pipe(
      map((data:any) => { 
      
        return data;
      }), catchError( error => {
        return throwError(error);
      })
    )
    
  }

  /*getItem( idx:number ){
    return this.data[idx];
  }*/
 
 
}
```

And Here is my pagina.component.ts file where I want to show the complete detailed Blog

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { StrapiService } from '../../../../services/strapi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagina',
  templateUrl: './pagina.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagina.component.scss']
})
export class PaginaComponent implements OnInit {

  data:any = {};


  constructor( private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
           private router: Router,
           public strapiserv:StrapiService
    ){ 

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params => {
      this.data = this.strapiserv.getData( params['id'] );
    });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

My routes are:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
    { path: 'pagina/:id', component: PaginaComponent },
];
```

Comment: What's happened ? Do you have any error ?

Comment: Hello Amadou!, The thing is that I don´t know how to

Comment: What you have done seems correct ! That's why I asked if you hae any error ? Like if the link doesn't work or anything else...

Comment: Hello Amadou!, When someone clicks this button from my blog.component.html: <a [routerLink]="[ './pagina',id ]" class="btn">Leer más</a>, the app takes you to another link named 'pagina.component' which contains the detail of that specific ID Blog, But I don´t know how to write the code to do that in the pagina.component.ts file

Comment: The app does not get me to the pagina.component file. What makes me think I am missing something

Comment: Also, this line shows one error in the pagina.component file. It is something wrong with the ID:                                                                                               this.data = this.strapiserv.getData( params['id'] );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with what you have done:

The 'i' is the index of the loop, not the 'id' you want to use. I guess the 'id' is a property of data, so you should point to data.id

You don't have to use relative path when using [routerLink] (with brackets)
so replace this:

```
[routerLink]="['./pagina',i]"
```

with this:

```
[routerLink]="['/pagina', data.id]"  // remove the '.'
```

Finally in your `blog.component.ts` file, your're receiving array of objects so you don't have to cast it as an array of string, `this.datas= res;` is enough

Comment: Hello Amadou, you were right. It worked using this code:                                                <a [routerLink]="['/pagina/',data.id]" class="btn">Leer más</a>

Comment: Now my 'pagina.component' shows the Blogs by ID.  Just I was missing to add an ngFor in the pagina.component.html, which displays all the blogs. Then I just want to show only the appropriate Blog by ID, and not all the blogs. I guess I must add a method to the service to do so, but that is a topic for another stack overflow.  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You may like to help me on this topic also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267849/how-to-show-a-blog-detail-by-id-in-angular